# One cross tab shows values of 10 queries Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10

I have 10 lists with queries and each of them have item called timetaken i want to show this item of the 10 lists in one cross tab in row and no coloumns show like 10 rows each for each timetkane in each of them

Thanks

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and rephrase your question.

Comment: How does question relate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24575950/cognos-creating-summary-cross-tab-from-10-queries? I would suggesting deleting one of them.